# Is it possible to apply functions to an external table DDL in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have JSONL data being loaded into a GCS bucket, and some "record" field types are blank (i.e., {}). So auto detecting the schema ends up creating a RECORD type which has no sub fields (this is not allowed in BigQuery).

As a workaround, I have created the external table as such:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`
OPTIONS
(
    uris=['gs://path/to/files/*'],
    format=JSON,
    ignore_unknown_values=true
)
```

(this table cannot be queried fully as I receive an error: `Unsupported empty struct type for field '<field name here>'`). So I create a view on top of this external table as such:

```
CREATE VIEW `my_table_view` AS
select TO_JSON_STRING(value) as column from `my_table`
```

and then I can successfully query this view (built on top of the external table) for any column.

My question is, can I skip creating the view and add this `TO_JSON_STRING` function in the external table definition itself? I have not been able to figure out how as I keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Do you want to do `TO_JSON_STRING` while creating an external table?

Comment: Yes, I want to create the external table with one column, namely `TO_JSON_STRING()` of the raw column itself.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for me to reproduce your scenario?